Screen resolution buffer broken on wine games after Linux kernel 5.15
I was just using Linux kernel 5.15 on my old laptop because in wine the game automatically loaded the screen resolution when changing the resolution. Now I can only accept default resolution.
Why did Linux purposely break features of their Linux kernel after 5.15? I can't use 5.15 on my current laptop cause it doesn't hold my Wi-Fi driver. I suppose I could but I would lose capability.
I currently boot 2 kernels the up to date standard kernel and the DRM kernel. But I really don't know really where to go from here. I tried messing with xrandr and couldn't get any results. I wonder if it has anything to do with a compositor.
How to adjust the frame buffer resolution in everything past 5.15 when I have to change screen resolution in Wine?

Why did Linux purposely break features ... how do you know that it was done on purpose?
